# total price in crystal report

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I try to get total of sale price in crystal report. In sale price  column amount is displayed by `quantity*net price = net value` now  if one sale order have multiple items then i want sum of all these sale price behalf of sale order

this is what i do

```
sale order   customer  mat name sale price
12223123     abc        books      120
112312342    xyz        comp        100
112312342    xyz        mouse        40
```

this is what i want

```
sale order   customer  mat name sale price   total
12223123     abc        books      120       120
112312342    xyz        comp        100      140*
112312342    xyz        mouse        40


*100+40=140
```

how i do this in crystal report???

and the query which i tried.

```
SELECT
    customer.custname1,ordhdeader.saleorder,material.matname,orddetail.netvalue as sale price
FROM
    ordhdeader
     left  join orddetail on  
    ordhdeader.saleorder = orddetail.saleorder 

      left   join customer on  ordhdeader.custno = customer.custno 
     left   join material on orddetail.matno=matmst.matno
```

Comment: Why comp total is 140 and mouse total isn't?

Comment: because mouse and comp have same sale order .. so one sale order has multiple items

Comment: and i want sum of all these items price behalf of sale order... if other sale order has 3 items then sum of 3 items and if another sale order has 5 items then i want sum of these 5 items

Comment: But they are both the same sale order,shouldn't they both get 140?

Comment: and i want sum of all these items price behalf of sale order... if other sale order has 3 items then sum of 3 items and if another sale order has 5 items then i want sum of these 5 items

Comment: Listen! you are not making any sense. Both mouse and comp is the same sale order, sum comp total suppose to be 140, and mouse total should be 140 as well!

Comment: ok so how i do this?

Comment: have you tried running totals in crystal reports?

Comment: yes i use shared formula.. 1) shared a as number
shared b as number
a=({smorddtl.netvalue})
b=b+a
formula=a
a=0
2)shared b as number
formula=b
b=0

Comment: this is a complex way of doing in crystal report... check my answer for running totals

Comment: @siva where is ur answer?

Comment: Just posted check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In field explore create a new `Running total` formula and give it a name.

Select `sale_price` in field to summarize part and type of summary is `sum`

In `Evaluate` select on change of field in that select `each record`

In `Reset` select `sale order` field

Place the running total on design